# How to describe uniform random variable with uniform random parameter?

Tags: random-variables

To preface, I know some basic calculus but not a lot about random variables. But I'm curious about the situation where $X$ is $ U(0,1)$ and $Y$ is $U(0,X)$. Is it possible to get the distribution or expected value of Y, and if so, is there a way to handle random variables with random parameters in general?

Comment: Yes, condition on $X$

Comment: If $Z\sim U(0,1)$  is independent of $X$ then $Y=XZ.$